# Convert datetime array to string - C#, Win 8

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-8, tostring, windows-8.1

I'm trying to go something really simple here and apparently not possible. I have a datetime array

```
DateTime[] dtArray =  new DateTime[50];
```

This has few dates. I need to convert this datetime array to a string to be able to store in ApplicationDataContainer.

```
string test = dtArray.ToString();
```

This gives me text DateTime[].. Is there no direct way to convert the whole array to string or do I have to use for loop and convert each in to string and concatenate it?

Comment: What do you want the string to look like?

Comment: ApplicationDataContainer only allows primitive datatype :(, @wudzik answer is correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) and [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
string test = string.Join(",",dtArray.Select(x=>x.ToString(format)));
```

above you can use custom format

Or shorter (without format)

```
string test = string.Join(",",dtArray);
```

Comment: Or just `string.Join(",", dtArray)` as of .NET 4.

Comment: @wudzik Thanks!! :D. This is how I'm using.
string test = string.Join("~", temp.Select(x=>x.ToString("d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));